# What would you call a person dumps his work on you

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

What would you call a person who systematically dumps his work on you in a bid to evade responsibilities (with a work philosophy that when you don't learn or do it, you are never given the responsibilities and thus have no fear of making mistakes) but cluelessly whines to the same people around him for not having all the benefits that they (the higher ranking hardest working colleagues) earn.

PS: Owing to a bad management (Racial discrimination, Poor work ethic,ignorance, etc), if it helps.

Comment: A shirker, perhaps.

Comment: Please look up _shirker_ in online dictionaries, and also look for synonyms