# What would you call a naive person who asks you for the information that he himself is supposed to work on it and submit to me

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

What would you call a guileless person (employee from another department) who repetitively asks you for the information that he himself is supposed to come up with to the point of annoyance like a illogical fool and inform me for us to process it (we are from two different department in one organization and I have to do his work for him and inform him and then he feeds the information in the system and generates report does the bureaucratic task of forwarding the paper work which really contain my hard work back to me).

The person is not shirking, he is simply blissfully unaware, feels entitled and expects/at times pushes other party to respond back with the information.
PS: Inaction from Bad self serving management - The Reason why nothing gets resolved.

Again, he is not slacking, he is upgraded without proper orientation and is ill informed about the protocols by his boss and thus seeks information outside of his department to generate the information based report and typically asks me to whom in reality he has to submit the report which contains the information. I am report recipient who is the informer too, while i am suppose to be report recipient only. shirking, slacking is when one is evading work or duty. He isn't aware that he is..Does it still make him a typical shirker.

Comment: Didn't you just ask the same question an hour ago? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/399110/what-would-you-call-a-person-dumps-his-work-on-you

Comment: Apparently, I can use Mjölnir only once per question. Today I learned.

Comment: "is suppose accomplish" needs work.

Comment: He's **off-topic**:  "Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic."